# Lua: Table expected, got nil

Tags: lua, lua-table

So, I’m having an issue while trying to split strings into tables (players into teams). When there are two players only, it works like a charm, but when there are 3+ players, this pops up: “*Init Error : transformice.lua:7: bad argument: table expected, got nil*”. Everything seems to be ok, I really don’t know what’s wrong. Can you guys please help me? Thanks! Here is my code:

```
ps = {"Player1","Player2","Player3","Player4"}
local teams={{},{},{}}

--[[for name,player in pairs(tfm.get.room.playerList) do
 table.insert(ps,name)
 end]]

table.sort(ps,function() return math.random()>0.5 end)
for i,player in ipairs(ps) do
  table.insert(teams[i%#teams],player)
  end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lua arrays start at index `1`, not `0`. In the case of when you have 3 players this line:

```
table.insert(teams[i%#teams],player)
```

Would evaluate to:

```
table.insert(teams[3%3],player)
```

Which then would end up being:

```
table.insert(teams[0],player)
```

And `teams[0]` would be `nil`. You should be able to write it as:

```
table.insert(teams[i%#teams+1],player)
```

instead.