# Trying to insert table into table without creating a new table when saving to a file

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

I am attempting to add a "recipe" (Table) into a file for future look up.
My issue is that when I upload the data into the file, it creates a new table and does not insert into the "Main" table as a nested table. This causes issues when trying to search for a "recipe" within the main "recipe book".
The following is the code for this section of the project. The issue I believe is near the uploading of the data to a file but I am stumped. Can someone explain what the heck I am doing wrong?

When I run the code a second time it adds in the information into the main table without issue, but it adds it under the original table.
When I run the code any more times it just adds in a new table.

Code:

```
--recursive search in--recursive search into tables
  local Deep = require "DeepPrint"
  
  --Working from the following info
  --http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/23076-crafting-api-learn-recipes/
  --the solution found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299162/lua-table-expected-got-nilo
  
  --variables--
  --data holding place for recipes
  Recipes = {}
  --Crafting Grid
  grid = {1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11};
  
  --check for recipe book, if exists then read the data 
  local readRecipe = fs.open("recipeBook.lua","r")
  if readRecipe == nil then
      print("recipe book not found")
  else
      recipeList = readRecipe.readAll()
      readRecipe.close()
      ok, Recipes = pcall(textutils.unserialize, recipeList)
      if not ok then
          return false, recipeList
      end 
      if type(Recipes) ~= "table" then
          print("Main table not found, creating base table")
          Recipes = {}
      end 
  end
if readRecipe == nil then
      print("recipe book not found")
  else
      recipeList = readRecipe.readAll()
      readRecipe.close()
      ok, Recipes = pcall(textutils.unserialize, recipeList)
      if not ok then
          return false, recipeList
      end 
      if type(Recipes) ~= "table" then
          print("Main table not found, creating base table")
          Recipes = {}
      end 
  end
  
  --get recipe location and details to push into recipeBook.lua
  itemLayout = {}
  for key,value in pairs(grid) do
      turtle.select(value)
      if turtle.getItemDetail() then
       details = turtle.getItemDetail()
       table.insert(itemLayout,{
       name = details.name,
       count = details.count,
       location = value
       })
       end
  end
--craft item to get the name of crafted item
  turtle.select(16)
  turtle.craft()
  itemMade = turtle.getItemDetail()
  
  --check if table exists and if not creates a table
  if not Recipes[itemMade.name] then
      print("didnt find the table for item, creating new table")
      Recipes[itemMade.name] = {}
  else
      print("found recipe")
  end
  
  --add in info into main product table
  Recipes[itemMade.name]["components"] = itemLayout
  Recipes[itemMade.name]["quantityMade"] = itemMade.count
  
  --add recipe to list
  local ok, str = pcall(textutils.serialize, Recipes)
  if not ok then
      return false, str
  else
  book = fs.open("recipeBook.lua","a")
  book.writeLine(str)
  book.close()
  end
```

Results in the following type of table

```
{
    [ "minecraft:crafting_table" ] = {
      components = {
        {
          location = 1,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
        {
          location = 2,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
        {
          location = 5,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
        {
          location = 6,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
      },
      quantityMade = 1,
    },
  }
{
    [ "minecraft:oak_button" ] = {
      components = {
        {
          location = 1,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
      },
      quantityMade = 1,
    },
    [ "minecraft:crafting_table" ] = {
      components = {
        {
          location = 1,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
        {
          location = 2,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
        {
          location = 5,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
        {
          location = 6,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
      },
      quantityMade = 1,
    },
  }
  {
    [ "minecraft:oak_button" ] = {
      components = {
        {
          location = 1,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
      },
      quantityMade = 1,
    },
  }
{ 
    [ "minecraft:oak_pressure_plate" ] = {
      components = {
        { 
          location = 1,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
        { 
          location = 2,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
      },
      quantityMade = 1,
    },
  }
{
    [ "minecraft:crafting_table" ] = {
      components = {
        {
          location = 1,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
        {
          location = 2,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
        {
          location = 5,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
        {
          location = 6,
          name = "minecraft:oak_planks",
          count = 1,
        },
      },
      quantityMade = 1,
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to this.

1. is due to the fact I had it appending to the file and not writing when uploading the information back to the file.

2)The second was the pointless array at the beginning with the variable Recipes, before even starting to gather the info from the file. This caused the upload to have another nest that wasn't needed